# Comparison Operator in Python Not Working as Expected

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

I am working on getting more familiar with python. To do this I am working on a rock, paper, scissors game. I have a class to handle the comparison of the values to determine a winner. The trouble is whenever I do the comparison using an overloaded greater than operator, the result is wrong only when rock is involved. I make a compare method to test if my logic is correct and it is. Is there something about the behavior of overloaded operators in python that is causing this?

My code:

```
import random

rock = "rock"
paper = "paper"
scissors = "scissors"
options = (rock, paper, scissors)

class RcpValue:
    def __init__(self, value = rock):
        self.__value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__value == other.__value:
            return True

        return False

    def compare(self, other):
        if (self.__value == rock) and (other.__value == paper):
            return False

        if (self.__value == rock) and (other.__value == scissors):
            return True

        if (self.__value == paper) and (other.__value == scissors):
            return False

        if (self.__value == paper) and (other.__value == rock):
            return True

        if (self.__value == scissors) and (other.__value == rock):
            return False

        if (self.__value == scissors) and (other.__value == paper):
            return True

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if (self.__value == rock) and (other.__value == paper):
            return False

        if (self.__value == rock) and (other.__value == scissors):
            return True

        if (self.__value == paper) and (other.__value == scissors):
            return False

        if (self.__value == paper) and (other.__value == rock):
            return True

        if (self.__value == scissors) and (other.__value == rock):
            return False

        if (self.__value == scissors) and (other.__value == paper):
            return True

def determine_winner(p1: RcpValue, p2: RcpValue):
    if p1.value == p2.value:
        return "Tied!"

    if p1.value > p2.value:
    #if p1.compare(p2):
        return "Player 1 wins"

    return "Player 2 wins"

def test():
    for i in options:
        for j in options:
            player1 = RcpValue(i)
            player2 = RcpValue(j)
            print(f"Player 1 chose: {player1.value}")
            print(f"Player 2 chose: {player2.value}")
            print(determine_winner(player1, player2))
            print()

test()
```

Output using `__gt__`:

```
Player 1 chose: rock
Player 2 chose: rock
Tied!

Player 1 chose: rock
Player 2 chose: paper
Player 1 wins

Player 1 chose: rock
Player 2 chose: scissors
Player 2 wins

Player 1 chose: paper
Player 2 chose: rock
Player 2 wins

Player 1 chose: paper
Player 2 chose: paper
Tied!

Player 1 chose: paper
Player 2 chose: scissors
Player 2 wins

Player 1 chose: scissors
Player 2 chose: rock
Player 1 wins

Player 1 chose: scissors
Player 2 chose: paper
Player 1 wins

Player 1 chose: scissors
Player 2 chose: scissors
Tied!
```

Output using `compare()`:

```
Player 1 chose: rock
Player 2 chose: rock
Tied!

Player 1 chose: rock
Player 2 chose: paper
Player 2 wins

Player 1 chose: rock
Player 2 chose: scissors
Player 1 wins

Player 1 chose: paper
Player 2 chose: rock
Player 1 wins

Player 1 chose: paper
Player 2 chose: paper
Tied!

Player 1 chose: paper
Player 2 chose: scissors
Player 2 wins

Player 1 chose: scissors
Player 2 chose: rock
Player 2 wins

Player 1 chose: scissors
Player 2 chose: paper
Player 1 wins

Player 1 chose: scissors
Player 2 chose: scissors
Tied!
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple issue: the comparison `if p1.value > p2.value` compares the strings `"rock"`, etc. that are assigned in each `RcpValue` instance, so the `__gt__()` method is never being called.

All you need to do is replace that line with `if p1 > p2`. Since `p1` and `p2` are `RcpValue` objects, the interpreter uses `RcpValue.__gt__()` to compare them. You could similarly replace `if p1.value == p2.value` with `if p1 == p2` since you wrote `RcpValue.__eq__()`.